# Excel to match the values within two worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

i need a macro/formula to compare the two cell range in a worksheet and return the corresponding value in the cell.

eg sheet:
in worksheet 1(sheet1)

```
AGE Description proof
1   8   
2   9   
3   2   
4   9   
5   5   
6   6   
7   0   
8   1   
9   2   
10  1
```

sheet2:

```
dates   1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th

0         1  1  2   2   3   3
1         2  3  5   6   7   8   
3         4  6  7   8   9   7 
5         6  7  8   9   10  11
7         8  9  10  11  12  13
10       11 12  13  15  16  18
12       13 15  16  18  19  21
15       16 30  31  45  46  60
30       31 33  34  37  38  40
```

from the above example if my range needs my expectation (eg in sheet1 Age: 1 and description: 8 then it should compare it with sheet2 and paste the value as 6th in sheet1 proof column). like these i need to fill all the fields

Comment: Your data is impossible to read. Can you explain what we are looking at? What are the column headings? In the first set, is the first column (2, 3, 4...) the row number or is it a value? Is the 2nd column (9. 2. 9...) Description?  I have no idea about the 2nd set of numbers as they certainly exceed what seems to be 6 column heads?

Comment: hi wayne G. Dunn, i am looking for a macro/formula that needs to match the data from sheet 1 looks like this 
AGE Description
1 3
2 9
3 2
4 9
5 5
6 6
7 0
8 1
9 2
10 11
 then i need to compare the values if 1 and 3 exists in sheet2 then it should return the value present in sheet2
dates 1st      2nd     3rd     4th
0 1 1 2 2
1 2 2 3 3
2 3 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8 9
7 8 9 10 11
here it should return the value as 3rd

Comment: I fixed your formatting so we can at least see the columns and rows. Now you need to give a VERY SPECIFIC example. You say if 'Age: 1 and description: 8', which I believe is "Find row with Age = 1 in ColA, then use the value found in ColB (which is 8). I have no clue what row or column you search next, or what you look for. You say 'compare it with sheet2' but you don't say if you are comparing the Age (1) in a Date column, or the Description (8). Please write the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: i need to compare the value from sheet2 in sheet2 it takes 1 from dates and then search the row for the value of 8 then it returns the value 6th

Comment: Is the following correct: Take the first value in AGE column (1) and find row in Sheet2 with a (1) in the DATE column.; then look in that row in sheet2 and see if you find a value of (8) [yes, it is in column '6th']; so in Sheet1, column PROOF, you enter '6th'????  If not, I give up. After that, NONE of your other combinations will match (no rows in Sheet2 with AGE of 2, 4, 6, 8 or 9) and no match on DESCRIPTION for the other AGES.  ??????

Comment: no i need to search the two values comparing from sheet1 if 1 and 8 exists then it should search for the same combination in row wise (sheet2) and then returns the coresponding column value

Comment: can you put output as well which you are expecting?

Comment: from sheet1 it contains 1 and 8. so it should search in sheet2 for 1 in first column and 8 in the coresponding row if it matches then return the column value as 6 th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you are

1. first matching sheets1.age with sheets2.dates and if you found a match then
2. You are searching Sheets1.description in sheets2.1st to Sheets2.6th and if you found a mtach then
3. You are selecting selecting *th(column name) from sheet2 and putting it into sheets1.proof.

I found only 1 match i.e. for the first observation

Below is the code

```
Sub checkNmatch()
```

Calculating the lastrow of sheet1 and sheet2 for automation

```
lastRowSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To (lastRowSheet1 - 1)
 For j = 2 To (lastRowSheet2 - 1)
```

Checking below if sheets1.age matches with sheets2.dates

```
   If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1) Then
```

If match found then searching Sheets1.description in sheets2.1st to Sheets2.6th

```
   For k = 2 To 7
   If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, k) Then
```

If match found then copying the column name of Sheet2  into Proof of sheet1

```
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, k)       
   End If
          Next
        End If
     Next
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: HI neo,ur code works well and fine if i had alphabets in the place of 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th like apple,banana,jack fruit, plumps. how to paste the alphabets in that place

Comment: sry dude i am new one to macro can u please suggest me the code to take the alphabets instead of numbers 1st, 2nd, 3rd

Comment: I have already updated the code with this Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, k) Now it picks, column name automatically, put apple , banana , 1st , 6th or whatever you want

Comment: dear neo,
your old code works well. but the updated one not working not yet picking any values in the sheet1. please do the needful

Comment: I just tested the code - copying the code from stackoverflow, and it is working for me, not sure why it is not working for you, could you close the excel and open it again?

Comment: @NEO_mental code works just fine. The issue is you need to be crystal clear on what you want -- and be able to communicate that to the people trying to help. Give VERY precise directions; cite row and column positions AND their values. The sample data you provided will ONLY MATCH ON ONE ROW!! (And it doesn't matter if your Sheet2 column heads are 1, 2, 3 or X, Y, Z, or Apple, Banana, ...)

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn  ..I assume you meant Vicky here ;)

Comment: @NEO_mental ... Sorry, yes, not directed to you  :(  I've reached my wits end trying to get clarity from the OP about what the issue is.  I meant 'Your code works just fine'....